# g_boxed_free: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_BOXED (boxed_type)' failed with gtk3 draw_area and nasm assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, gtk3, cairo

I'm currently working with linux nasm assembly and gtk3 drawing_area. I'm able to successfully show the gtk window and render components (The window apprears with a correct title and size). However, I'm unable to render anything to my gtk drawing_area using cairo.
Running the code below code I receive the following error:

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:10:00.207: g_boxed_free: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_BOXED (boxed_type)' failed
```

I suspect that the error lies in the draw_callback functions as I don't receive the error if I either leave it out or return immediately at tht start of the function. For some weird reason I do receive the error if I return after putting rdi to r14 and rsi to r15. The draw_callback-function gets connected to the draw event as I'm able to execute code in draw_callback function.
I have gotten the same logic and gtk calls written in COBOL&C to work so there should be nothing wrong with that. The issue most propably lies in my assembly skills (or lack thereof).
I was able to render other components such as checkboxes with the same layout so it should not be a problem.

```
;code.asm
    bits 64

    %define   GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL   0
    %define   GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER    1
    %define   FALSE                 0
    %define   TRUE                  1
    extern    gtk_init
    extern    gtk_window_new
    extern    gtk_window_set_position
    extern    gtk_window_set_default_size
    extern    gtk_window_set_title
    extern    gtk_box_new
    extern    gtk_container_add
    extern    gtk_drawing_area_new
    extern    cairo_move_to
    extern    cairo_rectangle
    extern    gtk_style_context_get_color
    extern    gtk_widget_get_style_context
    extern    cairo_show_text
    extern    cairo_fill
    extern    gtk_box_pack_start
    extern    gdk_cairo_set_source_rgba
    extern    gtk_widget_queue_draw
    extern    gtk_container_set_border_width
    extern    gtk_vbox_new
    extern    exit
    extern    gtk_box_pack_start
    extern    g_signal_connect_data
    extern    gtk_widget_show_all
    extern    gtk_main
    extern    gtk_main_quit
    extern    gtk_widget_show

section .bss
    color:      resq    1
    window:     resq    1   ; pointer to the GtkWidget, in this case the window
    drawing_area: resq    1
    vbox:    resq    1
    quit:       resq    1

section .data

    mainwindow:
    .title:     db  "title",0
    
    signal:
    .draw:  db  "draw", 0
    .destroy:   db  "destroy", 0

    height dd 1000
    width dd 1000

section .text
    global _start

_start:

    xor     rsi, rsi                  ; argv
    xor     rdi, rdi                  ; argc
    call    gtk_init

    mov     rdi, GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL
    call    gtk_window_new
    mov     qword[window], rax

    mov     rdi, qword[window]
    mov     rsi, GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER
    call    gtk_window_set_position

    mov     rdi, qword[window]
    mov     rsi, [height]
    mov     rdx, [width]
    call    gtk_window_set_default_size

    mov     rdi, qword[window]
    mov     rsi, mainwindow.title
    call    gtk_window_set_title

    mov rdi, qword[window]
    mov rsi, 2
    call gtk_container_set_border_width

    xor     r9d, r9d                 
    xor     r8d, r8d                
    xor     rcx, rcx                
    mov     rdx, gtk_main_quit      
    mov     rsi, signal.destroy     
    mov     rdi, qword[window]      
    call    g_signal_connect_data

    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, 5
    call gtk_vbox_new
    mov qword [vbox], rax

    mov     rdi, qword[window]
    mov     rsi, qword[vbox]
    call    gtk_container_add

    call gtk_drawing_area_new
    mov qword [drawing_area], rax

    call connect_draw

    mov rdi, qword [vbox]
    mov rsi, qword [drawing_area]
    mov rdx, 1
    mov rcx, 1
    mov r8, 0
    call gtk_box_pack_start
    
    mov rdi, qword[drawing_area]
    call gtk_widget_show

    mov rdi, qword[vbox]
    call gtk_widget_show

    mov rdi, qword[window]
    call gtk_widget_show
    
    call    gtk_main

    xor     rdi, rdi
    call    exit

;The graphics part starts here

connect_draw:
    xor     r9d, r9d      
    xor     r8d, r8d          
    xor     rcx, rcx 
    mov     rdi, qword[drawing_area]
    mov     rsi, signal.draw

    ;A gtk window reference
    mov     rdx, draw_callback
    call    g_signal_connect_data 
    ret


draw_callback: ;GBoolean (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
    mov r14, rdi; GtkWidget *widget
    mov r15, rsi ; cairo_t *cr
   
    mov rdi, r15
    mov rsi, 100
    mov rdx, 100
    mov rcx, 100
    mov r8, 100
    call cairo_rectangle ;void cairo_rectangle (cairo_t *cr, double x, double y,double width, double height);
    ;Nothing happens here

    ;Next lines attempt to fill the drawn rectangle
    mov rdi, r14
    call gtk_widget_get_style_context
; GtkStyleContext *
;   gtk_widget_get_style_context (GtkWidget *widget);

    mov rdi, rax
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, color
    call gtk_style_context_get_color 
;void
; gtk_style_context_get_color (GtkStyleContext *context,
;                              GtkStateFlags state,
;                              GdkRGBA *color);

    mov rdi, r15
    mov rsi, color
    call gdk_cairo_set_source_rgba
    ;void
    ;gdk_cairo_set_source_rgba (cairo_t *cr,
    ;                       const GdkRGBA *rgba);

    mov rdi, r15
    call cairo_fill
;void
;   cairo_fill (cairo_t *cr);

;A nice return value
    mov rax, FALSE
    ret
```

And finally here's how I compile, link and run the code (just to be safe)

```
nasm -felf64 -o code.o -l code.lst code.asm
ld -s -m elf_x86_64 code.o -o code -lc --dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lgtk-3 -lpthread -lcairo -lgobject-2.0  -lglib-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgdk-3
./code
```

Comment: This doesn't assemble. Please provide the full code, a Minimal Reproducible example.

Comment: I had some leftover code. Now fixed.

Comment: A possible problem is violating the x86-64 System V ABI by making a `call` with RSP not aligned by 16.  That's guaranteed on entry to `_start` (which isn't a function), but you some functions that use `call` without any push or `sub rsp,8`.  If that were the problem, you'd expect a segfault, though. (From a misaligned `movaps` to a local on the stack).

Comment: If you have equivalent C code, have you tried comparing `ltrace ./code` output to compare args passed to library functions?   (In this case, the output is nice and short, should be possible to compare by hand, although it doesn't decode any pointed-to structs so you can't fully verify args.  Disabling ASLR might help some, but addresses would still be different.)

Comment: I ran ltrace and found that my C code calls cairo rectangle with `cairo_rectangle(0x55f1f548ac00, 0x7f802e9f1700, 0x4074000000000000, 0x55f1f569d700) = 0` My assembly code calls it with `cairo_rectangle(0x18ae800, 100, 100, 100) = 0` I will investigate more later but it seems like I have to call with a mem address rather than a value.